# Traversing a tree from right to left

Tags: algorithm, tree

I was reading the book "Fundamentals of Algorithms" by Brassard and Bratley and there is a statement in the section on tree traversals that says:

> Preorder, postorder and inorder traversals explore the tree from left
>   to right. Three corresponding techniques explore the tree **from right
>   to left**.

What does it mean to traverse from right to left? My guess is that they mean tat a right-to-left preorder traversal is equivalent to a regular left-to-right postorder traversal? And that the inorder for both left-to-right and right-to-left are the exact same algorithm?

Comment: I think you just need to try to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood all the questions, so I will answer only one.

> What does it mean to traverse from right to left?

All of these tree traversal methods require recursion. In recursion you need to do something with element and traverse left/right tree. You have `*L*R*`. You can insert your `do something` instead of one of the `*`. And will get your pre/in/pos - order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple tree, a single node with two leaves:

```
        Mom
         ^
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
    Sally   Bob
```

Since there are three labels, there are six (three factorial) possible orders. Three of these correspond to left-to-right traversals, where `Sally` is named before `Bob`:

- Mom, Sally, Bob ← preorder. Mom is before the kids.
- Sally, Bob, Mom ← postorder. Mom is after the kids.
- Sally, Mom, Bob ← inorder. Mom is between the kids.

If we were to visit the kids in the opposite order (Bob first), then we would have right-to-left (*RTL*) traversal. (Bob's on the right, right?) Again, three possibilities:

- Mom, Bob, Sally ← RTL preorder. Mom is before the kids.
- Bob, Sally, Mom ← RTL postorder. Mom is after the kids.
- Bob, Mom, Sally ← RTL inorder. Mom is between the kids.

---

All of the above are *depth-first* traversals. That means that if we visit a child node (Sally, for example), we complete traverse that node before continuing with whatever is to be traversed next.